# How do I delete my Linux Foundation account?

Tags: account-management

I made a Linux Foundation account (https://linuxfoundation.org, account system on https://openprofile.dev) for some purposes last year, and now I want to delete it. However, looking around the website I don't see any way to delete my account, and searching the web hasn't been fruitful either. How do I delete my Linux Foundation account?

Answer (score 2):

From *Can you delete my SSO account?* section on the [LF - Wiki](https://confluence.linuxfoundation.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=28484692):

> We can now delete login accounts, please open a ticket with the account you would like to be deleted. https://jira.linuxfoundation.org/plugins/servlet/theme/portal/4/create/255
>
> In case you would like to remove all your personal data from LFX, please follow our Privacy Policy Process https://linuxfoundation.org/privacy-policy/